# Which should I be using: urlparse or urlsplit?

Tags: python, urllib, urlparse, urlsplit

Which [URL parsing function pair](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html) should I be using and why?

- [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and [`urlunparse`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunparse), or
- [`urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) and [`urlunsplit`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Directly from [the docs you linked yourself](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit):

> `urllib.parse.urlsplit(urlstring, scheme='', allow_fragments=True)`
>   This is similar to `urlparse()`, but does not split the params from the URL. This should generally be used instead of `urlparse()` if the more recent URL syntax allowing parameters to be applied to each segment of the path portion of the URL (see RFC 2396) is wanted.

Comment: Since those URLs (with parameters attached any path element) are rarely used in practice, perhaps it would be worth adding an example, showing the differences in the parsed results?  e.g. like here: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urlparse/#parsing

Comment: [Updated Python 3 link](https://pymotw.com/3/urllib.parse/#parsing) for those interested

Comment: Could you provide example URLs illustrating the difference? I've read the Python docs and briefly looked at RFC 2396, but it is unclear which type of URL parameters they are referring to other than the fact that they use a semicolon.

Answer (score 13):

Given the documentation you linked didn't include an example with an nonempty `params` I was also confused until I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988764/771768).

```py
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("http://example.com/pa/th;param1=foo;param2=bar?name=val#frag")
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/pa/th', params='param1=foo;param2=bar', query='name=val', fragment='frag')
```

---

*(Some history because I got nerd-sniped.)*

I'd never heard of the URL "parameters" other than url component params i.e. `/user/213/settings` or query params `/user?id=213` and I think it's essentially obsolete.

In the beginning, RFC 1738 [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.3) the HTTP URL to never allow `;` in the `path`:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
```

> Within the `<path>` and `<searchpart>` components, "/", ";", "?" are reserved.

`;` was reserved with special meaning in other schemes, [like](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.2.2) the ftp:// `url-path`:

```
<cwd1>/<cwd2>/.../<cwdN>/<name>;type=<typecode>
```

Apparently in 1995, RFC 1808 [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808#section-2.1) URL `params` as a top-level component between `path` and `query`:

```
<scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
```

---

Then in 1998, RFC 2396 [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3) URIs as having adjacent top-level components `path` and `query`:

```
<scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>
```

where the `path` is [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.3) as multiple `path_segments` that each could include `param`:

```
path          = [ abs_path | opaque_part ]
abs_path      = "/"  path_segments
path_segments = segment *( "/" segment )
segment       = *pchar *( ";" param )
```

---

Finally in 2005, RFC 3986 obsoleted RFC 1808 and 2396, [defining](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) `URI` similarly to RFC 2396:

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ] 

hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
            / path-absolute
            / path-rootless
            / path-empty
```

And the special syntax of `;params` is [considered](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) an opaque part of the URI syntax that may be specific to the HTTP(S) scheme or just some specific implementation:

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is considered opaque by the generic syntax.  URI producing applications often use the reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit scheme-specific or dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For example, the **semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to that segment**.  The comma (",") reserved character is often used for similar purposes.  For example, one URI producer might use a segment such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version 1.1 of "name", whereas another might use a segment such as "name,1.1" to indicate the same.  **Parameter types may be defined by scheme-specific semantics**, but in most cases **the syntax of a parameter is specific to the implementation of the URI's dereferencing algorithm.**

Answer (score 8):

**As the [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse-result-object) says**
`urlparse.urlparse` returns 6-tuple(with additional *parameter* tuple)
`urlparse.urlsplit` returns 5-tuple

> Attribute   |Index |   Value                                              |  Value if not present
> params    |     3      |  Parameters for last path element |   empty string

FYI: According to [RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#appendix-C), _parameter_ in URL specification
>  Extensive testing of current client applications demonstrated that
   the majority of deployed systems do not use the ";" character to
   indicate trailing parameter information, and that the presence of a
   semicolon in a path segment does not affect the relative parsing of
   that segment.  Therefore, parameters have been removed as a separate
   component and may now appear in any path segment.  Their influence
   has been removed from the algorithm for resolving a relative URI
   reference.

Comment: From your answer it is not clear which method you do advise to use.

Comment: It depends, if you needs parameter in URL then use urlsplit.