# What are the URL parameters? (element at position #3 in urlparse result)

Tags: python, url, url-parameters, urlparse

I've taken a look to `urlparse.urlparse` method documentation and I'm a little bit confused about what is the `parameters` part (not to be confused with the more familiar `query` part, that is what goes after the question mark and before the fragment part).

Wikipedia entry on URL's structure doesn't say anything about that, so could please anybody elaborate a little bit on this and possibly give some examples?

Comment: fascinating, this is the first time I've encounter them, found this http://doriantaylor.com/policy/http-url-path-parameter-syntax I also found this
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3 (last paragraph before query) and this
http://www.jtmelton.com/2011/02/02/beware-the-http-path-parameter/ <br> their rarely used, I think their meant to attach certain properties to paths .. maybe even control which version of segment you want to use, but this is just a hunch ...
either way thank you, for bringing it up.

Answer (score 35):

Wow... I was not aware of that, see example:

```
>>> urlparse.urlparse("http://some.page.pl/nothing.py;someparam=some;otherparam=other?query1=val1&query2=val2#frag")
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='some.page.pl', path='/nothing.py', params='someparam=some;otherparam=other', query='query1=val1&query2=val2', fragment='frag')
```

And help(urlparse.urlparse):

```
Help on function urlparse in module urlparse:

urlparse(url, scheme='', allow_fragments=True)
    Parse a URL into 6 components:
    <scheme>://<netloc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
    Return a 6-tuple: (scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment).
    Note that we don't break the components up in smaller bits
    (e.g. netloc is a single string) and we don't expand % escapes.
```